# Why does Google not index my "robots.txt"?

Tags: robots.txt, googlebot, sitemap.xml

I am trying to allow the Googlebot webcrawler to index my site. My `robots.txt` initially looked like this:

```
User-agent: * 
Disallow: / 
Host: www.sitename.com 
Sitemap: https://www.sitename.com/sitemap.xml
```

And I changed it to:

```
User-agent: * 
Allow: / 
Host: www.sitename.com 
Sitemap: https://www.sitename.com/sitemap.xml
```

Only Google is still not indexing my links.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to allow the Googlebot webcrawler to index my site.

1. **Robots rules has nothing to do with indexing!** They are ONLY about crawling ability. A page can be indexed, even if it is forbidden to be crawled!
2. `host` directive is supported **only** by Yandex.
3. If you want all bots are able to crawl your site, your robots.txt file should be placed under https://www.sitename.com/robots.txt, be available with status code 200, and contain:

   `User-agent: *
    Disallow:
    Sitemap: https://www.sitename.com/sitemap.xml`

Answer (score -1):

**From the [docs](https://moz.com/learn/seo/robotstxt):**

Robots.txt syntax can be thought of as the “language” of robots.txt files. There are five common terms you’re likely come across in a robots file. They include:

User-agent: The specific web crawler to which you’re giving crawl instructions (usually a search engine). A list of most user agents can be found here.

Disallow: The command used to tell a user-agent not to crawl particular URL. Only one "Disallow:" line is allowed for each URL.

Allow (Only applicable for Googlebot): The command to tell Googlebot it can access a page or subfolder even though its parent page or subfolder may be disallowed.

Crawl-delay: How many seconds a crawler should wait before loading and crawling page content. Note that Googlebot does not acknowledge this command, but crawl rate can be set in Google Search Console.

Sitemap: Used to call out the location of any XML sitemap(s) associated with this URL. Note this command is only supported by Google, Ask, Bing, and Yahoo.

Try to **specifically mention Googlebot** in your robots.txt-directives such as:

```
User-agent: Googlebot 
Allow: /
```

or **allow all web crawlers** access to all content

```
User-agent: * 
Disallow:
```

Comment: i change my robots.txt to                                  User-agent: * Allow: / Host: www.sitename.com Sitemap: https://www.sitename.com/sitemap